# Foundation 4 reveal not working only overlay shown

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I just started to use Foundation 4, thought i will give it a go after beeing a massive Twitter Bootstrap user.

There is one thing what i do not get.

No matter how i define my buttons to open my modal, just the overlay shows up nothing else.
Al files included correctly, checked console, no errors, checked log no errors.

here are my tries

**not woking**

```
<button data-reveal-id="myModal" data-reveal-ajax="{{ url('settings/portfolio-modal') }}">
    Click Me For A Modal
</button>
```

**not working either**

```
<a href="{{ url('settings/portfolio-modal') }}" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-reveal-ajax="true">
    Click Me For A Modal
</a>
```

the html what should be open

```
<div id="myModal">
    <h1>This is a modal</h1>
</div>
```

So could someone give me a hint?

PS: i am using Laravel php framework

Comment: Use dom checker to see if the target page is indeed placed in the current page's dom

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that the URL you load is configured in your route?

Also try with javascript

```
$('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open', '../../settings/portfolio-modal');
```

Comment: yes ofcourse, thats why i higlighted i recive no errors, as i was searching around on the net, lot of users struggle with this as well

Answer (score 0):

This bug fixed in foundation 5: 
https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/3444